# scoring profile in Azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azureportal, azure-search-.net-sdk

I tried creating a Scoring Profile in the Azure Search using the '.Net SDK' but it is not reflecting on the Azure portal. It is giving me `Bad Request` error at this line in the code.

```
results = indexClient.Documents.Search<ModelDetails>(searchText, parameters);
```

Is there any restriction/access permission needed for creating the Scoring Profile? Is it achievable through .net code?

If no, Please help me on how to create it through code.

Note: Even in the REST API implementations, I can't see any `POST` or `PUT` requests. Only `GET` requests are there in the examples provided in the Microsoft document.

Comment: Manasvi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are many issues with your question. First, we don't know how you created a Scoring Profile. Second, we don't know what parameters you're passing to your `Search` function. As it stands now, it will not be possible to say why you're getting the error. Please edit your question and include all the details that you can otherwise there's a strong possibility that this question will be closed because of lack of information provided.

Comment: Bad Request status code has an error message explaining what was the issue with the request. What is the error message?
PUT and POST index create / update requests are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/create-index)